# SQL: Query entries where timestamp >= 30 days ago

Tags: sql

My entries have timestamps like 1488446089, 1469525148 etc.

I am trying to get entries not older than 30 days.
Another use case would be to get entries >= YEAR(2016)

Whats wrong with this query. It return all results an ignores the where clause

```
"SELECT DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(createdTime)) AS ForDate,
          COUNT(*) AS NumPosts
          FROM  Posts
          WHERE DATE_SUB(from_unixtime(createdTime), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
          GROUP BY DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(createdTime))
          ORDER BY ForDate"
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? And why aren't you using a proper `timestamp`? Then you could simply do `where createdtime >= current_date - 30`

Answer (score 2):

seems you don't have a filter (yoy don't compare values)  eg `date_sub(...)  >= DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(createdTime))`

```
"SELECT DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(createdTime)) AS ForDate,
        COUNT(*) AS NumPosts
        FROM  Posts
 WHERE DATE_SUB(from_unixtime(createdTime), INTERVAL 30 DAY) >= DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(createdTime))
        GROUP BY DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(createdTime))
        ORDER BY ForDate"
```